# Android post values to MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql

I work on an Android project, in which I use `AsyncTask` to send `nameValuePairs` to webservice.
I use PHP code below to send data from application to database:

```
<?php
  require_once('dbConnect.php');

  $studentid = $_POST['name'];
  $classid = $_POST['classid']
  $studentid = $_POST['studentid'];
  $start = $_POST['start'];
  $end = $_POST['end'];
  $startsig = $_POST['startsig'];
  $endsig = $_POST['endsig'];

  $sql = "insert into signature (studentid,classid,start,end,startsig,endsig) values ('$studentid','$classid','$start','$end','$startsig','$endsig')";
  if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    echo 'success';
  }
  else{
    echo 'failure';
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Values in `dbConnect.php` file are correct. Database schema looks like this.
[image]

I checked, application sends out data successfully, but when I try to access PHP file above from browser I get a `HTTP 500` error.
What else should I check in this case?

Comment: First step is debugging. The following lines of code will make PHP send the error text in the response. Examine the response and you will see the error.

    `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
    `ini_set("display_errors", "1");` Put these at the top of your PHP script, after the opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems I noticed in your code you didn't put a semicolon after

```
$classid = $_POST['classid']
```

And also why are you assigning two different post values to same phpvariable  `$studentid = $_POST['name'];` and  `$studentid = $_POST['studentid'];`.Anyways `$studentid` will have the last assigned value `$_POST['studentid']`

Try debugging for more errors